# Display User's 'is_active' status in TabularInline Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a Client object that has a User and a Company objects as FKs

```
class Client(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True)
```

In my CompanyAdmin, I want a list of all clients as a TabularInline, including the `active` status of each client (based on user object)

```
class CompanyClients(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Client
    fields = ('user', 'master')

class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CompanyClients]
```

I want to add a column in my TabularInline to indicate that that user is active or not. I tried using `'user__is_active'` to my fields but I get this error:

```
Unknown field(s) (user__is_active) specified for Client
```

I just want an indication even if read-only (which I tried by putting a `readonly_fields` and it didn't work too), not looking to save/edit each client user's active status value from the Tabular form.

How can I approach this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add your query you are making to get the user.

Comment: I am not making any queries to get user, it's a field in the Client object, and Django is just fetching that based on variable name.

Comment: please share your user and company model to better clerify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CompanyClients(admin.TabularInline):
     model = Client
     fields = ('user', 'master','user__active)
```

**user__active**

Comment: I get the same error
Unknown field(s) (user__active) specified for Client